# Spring Boot with embedded tomcat creates empty directories in temp folder

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have created Spring boot application which runs on CentOS machine.
While the application is running there are some empty directories created in temp folder as below - with **tomcat.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.8080**

```
[root@CentOS-QA-125 backend-service]# cd /tmp/
[root@CentOS-QA-125 tmp]# ls
hsperfdata_nobody                                                        tomcat.4470692394951712929.8080  tomcat.7632125794043236543.8080
hsperfdata_root                                                          tomcat.4549830896347164779.8080  tomcat.7785504846258388922.8080
tomcat.4745791246199154712.8080  tomcat.7815834833588539762.8080
tomcat.118007245717039284.8080                                           tomcat.4851962228372473264.8080  tomcat.7824875841582997143.8080
tomcat.1313023034740625177.8080                                          tomcat.486137861122989407.8080   tomcat.785539555498439789.8080
tomcat.1334256488557704195.18080                                         tomcat.4981472070680071975.8080  tomcat.7897404027847452187.8080
tomcat.1361637523333369924.8080                                          tomcat.4997350422186621454.8080  tomcat.8298403342090061380.8080
tomcat.1454027871428296243.8080                                          tomcat.5096017063187125774.8080  tomcat.8456200677158959325.8080
tomcat.1468597706309242944.8080                                          tomcat.5183109189826449002.8080  tomcat.859127774801375492.8080
tomcat.1782179912761690122.8080                                          tomcat.5246047423134380844.8080  tomcat.8706261412802589755.8080
tomcat.1798168479970927044.8080                                          tomcat.5636031847701212066.8080  tomcat.8786479103113979810.8080
tomcat.1905491338162816307.8080                                          tomcat.5671250823815892425.8080  tomcat.8800584963400743657.8080
tomcat.1926407421149883221.18080                                         tomcat.5802754901492244418.8080  tomcat.8909628064306544136.8080
tomcat.2050642845396410198.8080                                          tomcat.5924561432335548181.8080  tomcat.8938301541068118051.8080
tomcat.2816928811999489865.8080                                          tomcat.594350763280186022.8080   tomcat.9213584206441849130.8080
tomcat.3155277784350207518.8080                                          tomcat.5963678300016740318.8080  tomcat-docbase.307198159312951369.8080
tomcat.3269295996451092693.8080                                          tomcat.603447849720662395.8080   tomcat-docbase.3650447568706516898.8080
tomcat.3296485328264645198.8080                                          tomcat.6126378381932430481.8080  tomcat-docbase.4418676716679207372.8080
tomcat.3478407594042395125.8080                                          tomcat.6298722759484433761.8080  tomcat-docbase.5455871628364634312.8080
tomcat.3568390261957689663.8080                                          tomcat.6506313869507286672.8080  tomcat-docbase.7102967207191677253.8080
tomcat.3582019931059397831.8080                                          tomcat.6600111490334966013.8080  tomcat-docbase.7724473308663758338.8080
tomcat.3690945660484868972.8080                                          tomcat.6664103181543225787.8080  tomcat-docbase.931779527920948070.8080
tomcat.3710144079209801015.8080                                          tomcat.6683066154461629639.8080  tomcat-docbase.932218040353239650.8080
tomcat.4154490372779164762.8080                                          tomcat.7016719473998097349.8080  appl
tomcat.4218042511249324079.8080                                          tomcat.711724724349148228.8080   appl
tomcat.4266966067732443088.8080                                          tomcat.7166943087383096944.8080
tomcat.4434690235718477600.8080                                          tomcat.7523973379731195016.8080
```

Is there any way to limit or avoid creation of these folders?
Is there any way we can redirect these folders to some other location?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5009

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control the location of the directory using `server.tomcat.basedir`. As you have observed, it defaults to a temporary directory, but you can configure a different location if needed.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to control the location of a directory using "server.tomcat.basedir". Can we limit the number of tomcat files or delete the files after the count reaches some threshold?

Comment: This does not work, as there are two locations, and the static resources are in the temp 8080 folder

Answer (score 0):

use the option -Djava.io.tmpdir=<some_directory> works always in the server startup-arguments

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the same question, so looking in the spring boot documentation, I found the following:

in your application.properties you add.

```
server.tomcat.access-log-enabled = false
```